# Python Large bytearray Memory

Tags: python, memory, arrays

Suppose i create a large bytearray. Lets say 1000000 bytes or 1mb total. Does the interpreter reserve 1mb in memory or use memory as the byte array fills. Meaning does a mostly empty bytearray of 1000000 bytes used 1mb in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is allocated/reserved on construction. The line bellow will increase the memory usage of the interpreter by ~100MB on my system.

```
b = bytearray(1024*1024*100)
```

If the documentation does not mention it, I guess its up to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns the size of an object in bytes:

```
In [242]: sys.getsizeof(bytearray(10**6))
Out[242]: 1000025
```

So indeed `bytearray(10**6)` uses about 1MB of space.

Note that while `sys.getsizeof` gives an accurate answer for bytearrays, if applied to a *container* such as a list, it only gives the size of the container, not including the container's contents.

If you need to compute the size of an object including its contents, there is [a recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504) (referenced in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)) for that.